# Not all html is parsing Beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to parse the following:

```
<p class="has-text-align-center inherit-font" id="latest-buy"><strong>Buy</strong> 1 USD at 7,100 LBP</p>
```

But I am getting this:

[image]

the exchange rate is not showing. why is that?
here is my code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

html = Request('http://lirarate.com/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/86.0.4240.183'})
webpage = urlopen(html).read()
only_p_tags = SoupStrainer("p")

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser',parse_only=only_p_tags).prettify()

print(soup)
```

Comment: Look like the content of this div is loaded dynamically, so a better approach to getting this data might be to use something like `selenium`.

Comment: Because they are added by javascript and urllib does not run javascript. You have to use Selenium to be able to run the scripts in a browser and then extract the data that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the requests it sends, you will see that all data are readily available as JSON. You can directly request the json (the whole time series), instead of parsing the page html (page being populated with javascript and you will need tool Selenium). Now, there is a catch - from time to time it rejects the request and you get status 401 message. It looks it's based on making too many requests one after another. You can play with this and experiment

```
import requests
import datetime

url = 'https://lirarate.com/wp-json/lirarate/v2/rates'
payload = {'currency':'LBP'}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://lirarate.com/'}

response = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)

rates = response.json()
# parse the json response

try:
    # last buy
    last_buy_date, last_buy_rate = rates['buy'][-1]
    last_sell_date, last_sell_rate = rates['sell'][-1]
except KeyError:
    print(rates.get('message', rates))
    print('There was error. Try again.')
else:
    # convert to datetime
    last_buy_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(last_buy_date/1000)
    last_sell_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(last_sell_date/1000)
    print(f"{last_buy_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')} buy 1 USD at {last_buy_rate}")
    print(f"{last_sell_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')} sell 1 USD at {last_sell_rate}")
```

output

```
2020-11-03 17:34:10 buy 1 USD at 7100
2020-11-03 17:34:10 sell 1 USD at 7050
```

I cannot help but notice that it looks like the rates are reversed, i.e. YOU can buy at 7100 and sell at 7050. Not that they buy at 7100 and sell at 7050.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply and effort. i have one question as the output is outdated. it is showing the ER for yesterday and it is different from what it is now. why is that?

Comment: i need to say that i a beginner in this, and don't have much experience. my goal is to have it running and print the last time it was updated on the website along with the ER. like what you did but having it the latest data

Comment: at the time when I posted it was the latest data. I need to look further into it. There is one extra param `_ver=t202011410` which may be needed. I will look into it

Comment: how did you find the JSON link

Comment: can we also make it that we extract the rates and dates from the webpages so that we don't receive errors if we couldn't access the JSON file? but do we make it that the rates show up in the HTML code when parsing

Comment: I don't about WE part.:-) I just try to help and try to guide you in some direction. You may as well try just to parse the html if you wish as the other answer suggests. This is not code writing service after all.

Comment: as you may realize this is the first time I do anything like this, even posting on StackOverflow. It most probably was the case with yourself when you first started, having someone guiding you all the way through it. regarding the HTML parsing, nothing showed up in the p tag as i stated. you said to use selenium which i never heard of.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to fetch the appropriate HTML-element from your `soup` like this:

```
soup.findAll("p", {"id":"latest-buy"})
```